# Comment section below my answer is abused as a pillory. What to do?

Tags: support, status-completed, comment-flags

Yesterday someone posted a not-so-good question on SO but I answered it anyway. Perhaps that was a mistake, but I did. 
Shortly after that a discussion between a high-rep user and me started in the comments. It was based on a misunderstanding. He thought I'd beg for credits but it was just the other way round: I wanted to say that the other guy who answered deserves the credits instead of me. Before it was clear that he was mistaken, he (the high-rep user) flagged me for moderator attention. I don't know the exact reason but I think it was "pushing an OP to vote for me".

After a while we were clear and we both undid our worst OT comments. Perhaps a mod did also, I don't know.

Today the high-rep user again posts comments which I feel are just anger on the OP. The question was not *that* bad but it also showed that the OP has now clue of programming. In fact, a tutorial would have been the right advice for him.

What I'm asking is:

How should I handle the comments which I consider just anger on the OP?

They are all below my answer, so easiest would be to simply delete my answer to get rid of them. Should I?

Comment: Flag as unconstructive.

Comment: Note that your actual question appears to be *"How should I handle comments which I consider just anger on the OP?"*, in which case the context is irrelevant and you should flag them as unconstructive (or, if they're rude or offensive anger, as that). The location of those comments doesn't matter, and if your answer is upvoted it you shouldn't delete it just to remove them.

Comment: Well, I'm not absolutely sure. I'm not a native English speaker. I know it would help you if you could see the posts, but I don't want to blame a 90.000 rep person for no valid reason.

Comment: If that user is a high rep and is a mature person, he will explain himself. And since you're not an english native speaker, he will understand the confusion, there shouldn't be any problem. And find the post within your history is quite easy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899315/perl-program-to-find-matching-words-in-a-paragraph/37899810#37899810

Comment: Best to not pay too much attention to boring din, simply flag such a comment as "no longer needed".

Comment: @HansPassant This is almost 2 years old. Someone apparently felt a typo needed fixing...

Comment: @Machavity LOL, yes, I was surprised myself by the little red indication in my top bar and couldn't remember this question. I even had to lookup what a pillory is.